# How to log the current time in JMeter Webdriver sampler

Tags: jmeter, webdriver

I want log the current time to the JMeter log from the JMeter Webdriver sampler.

I am using the below code in the Webdriver sampler which is logging the time in milliseconds but the problem is my  Webdriver sampler has a waiting time of 2 minutes. The getStartTime() and getEndTime() functions are considering the sampler waiting time also. 
Is it any other way to get the current time from the Webdriver sampler? I  want to measure the time taken between two actions in the browser.

WDS.log.info(WDS.sampleResult.getStartTime())

WDS.log.info('WDS.sampleResult.getEndTime())

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can record start and end time using [Date.prototype.getTime()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime) function like:

```
var before = new Date().getTime()
// here is the code which duration you would like to measure
var after = new Date().getTime()

WDS.log.info('Time taken = ' + (after - before) + ' ms')
```

Demo:

[image: JMeter WebDriver time between events]

See [The WebDriver Sampler: Your Top 10 Questions Answered](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/webdriver-sampler-your-top-10-questions-answered) for more WebDriver sampler tips and tricks

Answer (score 0):

Exclude the wait time by covering only the required code block with the start time and end time function.

Ex:-

```
WDS.log.info(WDS.sampleResult.getStartTime())

---some code

WDS.log.info('WDS.sampleResult.getEndTime())
```

Wait for two minutes..wait(2)

```
WDS.log.info(WDS.sampleResult.getStartTime())

--some code

WDS.log.info('WDS.sampleResult.getEndTime())
```

In this way, wait time is excluded from the calculation.

This is not the best solution but one which I can think of.